# can't get span text inside of a ul using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape reviews from a website to be specific I'm trying to get the texts from inside a span but I get no results. I'm new at Python and scraping so I don't know exactly what I'm doing.

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr"
req = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')

activites = soup.find_all('div', class_="RF_CONTENT")

for activite in activites:
    NickName = activite.find("span", class_="RFW_ACTIVITY_SECTION_ACTIVITY_FEED_ELEM_RESUME_NICKNAME").text
    Name = activite.find("span", class_="RFW_ACTIVITY_SECTION_ACTIVITY_FEED_ELEM_RESUME_ACH_NAME").text
    print(NickName)
    print(Name)
```

Here is the HTML I'm trying to get data from:

```html
<div class="RFW_ACTIVITY_SECTION_ACTIVITY_FEED_ELEM_RESUME">
<div class="RF_CONTENT">
<p><a href="https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions/2814793-trouve-inadmissibile-ligne-active-partir-20-novembre-realiser-commande-3-11" target="_blank">

<span class="RFW_ACTIVITY_SECTION_ACTIVITY_FEED_ELEM_RESUME_NICKNAME">Celia q.</span>
    <span class="RFW_ACTIVITY_SECTION_ACTIVITY_FEED_ELEM_RESUME_ACTION"> a posé une question: Je trouve inadmissibile que ma ligne ne soit active qu'a partir du 20 novembre en ayant réaliser la commande le 3/11 ?</span><span class="RFW_ACTIVITY_SECTION_ACTIVITY_FEED_ELEM_RESUME_DATETIME">Il y a 2 minute(s)</span></a>
</p>

<div class="RFW_ACTIVITY_SECTION_ACTIVITY_FEED_SCORE">20  <span class="RF_TEXT_INDICE"> pts</span></div></div>
</div></li><li class="RFW_ACTIVITY_SECTION_ACTIVITY_FEED_ELEM">

<div class="RFW_ACTIVITY_SECTION_ACTIVITY_FEED_ELEM_PERFORMER">
<img src="https://api.rocketfid.com/media/default/rainbow/user/" alt="">
</div>
```

You can see it for yourself [here](https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr). My code returns no results.

here is a photo of reviews :
[image: reviews]

Comment: I took a look at the website and the code. It seems as either the url you provided is wrong, or the `popup` that shows up when you enter is masking the html you want.

Comment: Also, the source of information is unclear. Can you provide an image of which reviews you want extracted?

Comment: Yes sure  i'll provide a photo in the post

Comment: It is dynmically rendered means it takes some time to load so you can not to retrive from `bs4`  it only renders static data so you have to use `selenium` for that

Comment: thank you so mouch for this advice , like i said im new to this so i'll start looking for a selenuim solution

Comment: @BhavyaParikh it can be parsed by making a direct request call to website API/server. `Dev tools -> Network -> Fetch/XHR -> find an appropriate name (in this case "5/") -> Headers tab -> grab URL -> make a request`

Answer (score 1):

You can parse this data by making a direct request to the website API/Server, without using `selenium` for such a task.

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/cant-get-span-text-inside-of-a-ul-using-beautifulsoup#main.py):

What about [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), if no `user-agent` is being passed into request `headers` while using `requests` library it defaults to [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) so websites might understand that it's a bot/script, and block a request. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

In this case, it would work without `user-agent` but in most cases, it's needed to act as a "real" user visit, but again, only adding `user-agent` won't be enough in some cases, if so, additional request headers need to be added.

```py
import requests, json

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-instance": "rainbow"  # only this matter, otherwise it will blow up with 501 error
}

response = requests.get("https://api.rocketfid.com/activity/cache/all/0/5/", headers=headers).text

# print data to see the actual JSON string
# and grab additional data you want the same way as shown below
# simpy add additional variable and access it by KEY
data = json.loads(response)

for result in data:
    nick_name = result["performer"]["nickname"].title()

    # if data in achievement is empty -> then its located in the action key
    # using try/except is a one way of handling it
    try:
        name = result["achievement"]["name"]
    except:
        name = result["action"]["name"]

    try:
        score = result["achievement"]["score"]
    except:
        score = result["action"]["score"]

    # additional data here.. 

    print(f"{nick_name}\n{name}\n{score}\n")


# output
'''
Adrien S.
En savoir plus
10

Adrien S.
 a posé une question: Remboursement clé 4g ?
20

Marie-Claude P.
Première fois
20

Marie-Claude P.
 a répondu à la question: Comment supprimer l’autre numéro de contact dans mes préférences de contact ?
10

Marie-Claude P.
a fait la première réponse à une question
20
'''
```